# Office Communicator 2007: Open conversation window via link in tab

Tags: html, office-2007, office-communicator

I've integrated a web app inside the Communicator client as a "context-sensitive custom tab".

Our app needs to be able to open a conversation window with a given user via a click on a link in the web page. With Communicator 2005 we could just use an `<a>` tag with the SIP URI of the user:

```
<a href="sip:user@ourcompany.com">User</a>
```

With Communicator these links no longer work inside our tab. However, if I load up the web page in Internet Explorer, the links work.

Any idea what I need to do to get them working in the tab for Communicator 2007?

Answer (score 4):

My solution is this

```
`<a href="im:<sip:user@ourcompany.com>">User</a>`
```

You can also chat to many people like this:

```
`<a href="im:<sip:user1@ourcompany.com><sip:user2@ourcompany.com><sip:user3@ourcompany.com>">Chat to Us</a>`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work for me in my communicator 2007 tab. It works in IE though.

Comment: @Tom--G: can i set text message to that chatwindow? e.g. in mailTo we can attach subjet also. Same way can i set some message here?

Comment: Is it possible to open a group chat, by referencing more than one person?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching for some time I've not been able to come up with anything better than the following. It's based on the answer given [in this thread on MDSN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/99d5bec4-cddc-463d-adff-59c45c92a529).

I've added an `onlick` event handler to the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openConversationWindow(sip:user@ourcompany.com);">User</a>
```

Which calls:

```
function openConversationWindow(sip)
{
    var newWindow = window.open(sip);
    newWindow.close();
}
```

This has the distinct disadvantage of rapidly opening and then closing an Internet Explorer window but is the only way I've been able see of making these links work again in Communicator 2007.